# Jquery AJAX POST to IE 7, handle response

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, requirejs

I have read many different solutions to this on here but I can't get anything to work.  Basically, I am using the [**jQuery form plugin**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to do the below POST.  It works perfectly, and all the correct `alert`s fire, however it *ALWAYS* redirects to the response.  So if I get a 200 HTML response It will show it and remove the form page.  Same with a 400 would show me IE 7's 400 error page.  What am I missing to prevent this redirect??

```
    var $form = $("#myform");
    $form.submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        $form.ajaxSubmit({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),

            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                alert("sending");
            },
            success: function(data, status) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(data, status) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

**UPDATE**

I was not correct in what I said.  The alerts DO NOT fire.  Hopefully that helps.  The alerts were firing and it worked correctly (including supressing the redirect) in IE 10 running in IE 7 mode.  Except for the fact that it called the `success` method when receiving a 400.  But it did not redirect.  I then tested on native IE 7 in a VM and there were no alerts fired and it did redirect.

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry to the internets... The entire script was not being run in IE 7.  Please see my answer below.

Comment: IE... seven?!  Do you really need to support that?  I'm so sorry :(

Comment: Man you have no idea.  I wish I didn't.

Comment: I feel your pain, man.  I once spent most of a week fixing an ASP classic site to work in IE 7 :/

Comment: Just to check, you're using [this plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), yes?  http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: between jquery and polyfills etc etc etc it makes life a pain.  Although one thing I will say, is that it helped me catch some things.  Spots that could have been done better than modern engines 'auto fixed' for me that it did not.

Comment: That is the correct plugin, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [**requirejs**](http://requirejs.org/) to load my scripts, and for some reason the [**domReady!**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) module was keeping the script from loading in IE 7. because of the `!`.  So wrapped around the code above was this:

```
define(['domReady!', 'jquery.form'], function() {
    //code from question
});
```

I changed this to the following, and it started to work:

```
define(['domReady', 'jquery.form'], function(ready) {
    ready(function() {
        //code from question
    });
});
```

Now I just have to figure out why it still calls `success` when the server sends back a `400` error.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return false;` to the end of your event hook; some browsers don't properly support `preventDefault()`, and expect an explicit `false` return value.

```
var $form = $("#myform");
$form.submit(function(e) {

    $form.ajaxSubmit({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),

        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            alert("sending");
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(data, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: yes sorry, i actually have that in my code and forgot to include it here when i trimmed down.  still no go.  I updated my question to include it.

Comment: Then I have no idea, sorry :)